# Could Not Open the Database. Login Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I have the following connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ContextName" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ServerName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I run my app, i receive the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application, Cannot open database “” requested by
>   the login. The login failed

The error appears in this piece of code:

```
Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("ContextName");
```

I am sure that the current user has all permissions. I have also tried idea from [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/) article, but it did not work. 
Also I know that the database is not existing and I expect it to be created after the first get request.
Any ideas how I could create the database without starting the app? Or how could I fix this problem in general?

Comment: You need to have a database with correct permission before connecting with your website. Also, the Data Source in the connectionString is server name and Catalog is the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going to the database and go to properties, there you will find an option of connection string that can be easily used directly in the projects.